# How to determine the coords for the cell that is on the edge of a grid that intersects a line that extends from a source cell at a given angle?

Tags: trigonometry

How do you determine the coordinates for the cell that is on the furthest edge of a grid that intersects an imaginary line that extends from a source cell at a given angle.  The grid has a finite size of x number of rows and columns.  The image below shows illustrates the problem with two example angles on a grid that is 12 rows X 8 columns.  The green colored cell is the source cell.  The red colored cells are the edge cells that I am trying to determine the cell coordinates.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question after some thought. It's basic linear algebra.  First, find the equation of the source cell line.  Then solve where the line intersects the X axis or Y axis of the grid edge.